# Find the length of AP such that $\theta$ maximum.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

Find the length of AP such that $\theta$ maximum.

[image]

First, I think to construct a function length of AP with variable $\theta$ ($AP(\theta)$).

Next, we find maximum $\theta$ by equation $\dfrac{d AP(\theta)}{d\theta}=0$.

After we find maximum $\theta$, we subtitute to function $AP$ and we get the value AP such that $\theta$ maximum.

Now, I think about over a hour to find $AP(\theta)$ and I can't find it. I don't know how to find function $AP(\theta)$. Anyone can give me hint to find $AP(\theta)$?

Comment: **Hint** Compute the two other angles first.

Comment: To use calculus one needs to express $\theta$ in terms of $AP$ and then use $\theta'(AP)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the angles $\alpha$, $\theta$, $\beta$ from above and below. Hence we have
$$\tan\theta=\tan(\pi-(\alpha+\beta))=-\tan(\alpha+\beta)=-\frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}.$$
Set $AP=x$, then we have $\tan\alpha=\frac{4}{5-x}$, $\tan\beta=\frac{7}{x}$. Hence
$$\tan\theta=-\frac{\frac{4}{5-x}+\frac{7}{x}}{1-\frac{28}{(5-x)x}}=\frac{35-3x}{x^2-5x+28}.$$
It suffices to find the maximum value of $\tan\theta$. This can be done easily by differetiating. We omit it here.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let solve this problem as geometric, not trigonometric or calculus problem. Let consider two positions of point $P$ shown in the picture. Angle $CP_1D$ is inscribed angle of larger circle and angle $CPD$ is inscribed angle of smaller circle. As chord $CD$ is fixed so angle $CP_1D$ is less than angle $CPD$, then for maximum angle $CPD$ radius of circle has to be minimum, then circumcircle of $CPD$ has to be tangent to $AB$. Let center of this circle is $O$. Then using Pythagoras theorem one can show

$$BP^2=CO^2-(BC-OP)^2=r^2-(4-r)^2=8r-16$$
$$AP^2=DO^2-(AD-OP)^2=r^2-(7-r)^2=14r-49$$
$$7BP^2=7\cdot 8r-7\cdot 16=56r-112=4(AP^2+49)-112=4AP^2+84$$
Let $AP=x$, then $BP=5-x$ and
$$7(5-x)^2=4x^2+84$$
$$175-70x+7x^2=4x^2+84$$
$$3x^2-70x+91=0$$
$$x=\frac{35-2\sqrt{238}}{3}$$
Another root is greater than 5 and relates to irrelevant case when circle is tangent to continuation of $AB$.

Comment: Impressive geometric solution.